After manipulation of an expression, argument of a function doesn't simplify anymore
I have an expression in an argument of a function that I cannot seem to simplify.
I made use of this answer From exponent of sum to product of exponents
E^(-(1/18) I (9/2 (E^(-I gmt) + E^(I gmt)) + 
   1/2 (E^(-3 I gmt) + E^(3 I gmt))) m \[Pi])
% /. Power[E, a__] :> Power[E, Expand[a]]
% /. Power[E, a__] :> Power[E, ExpToTrig[a]]
% //. E^(a_ + b_) :> Defer[E^a E^b]
expr = % /. 
  Power[E, z__ Cos[th__]] :> 
   Sum[I^n BesselJ[n, -I z] Exp[I n th], {n, -Infinity, Infinity}] (* 
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion *)

What I get is an expression containing
BesselJ[1/2 (-I) (-1) I m Pi]

For some reason, this expression is in a certain state, that doesn't allow the simplification of the argument to m Pi/2. If I simply do
Simplify[1/2 (-I) (-1) I m Pi]

Then it works flawlessly ...
What can I do to convince Mathematica to do so, without converting the sum of Bessel functions back to a single exponent of a cosine or sine?

Try substitute BesselJ[n, Times[z]] in your replacement expression.

Not sure what you mean. expr = % /.    Power[E, z__ Cos[th__]] :>     Sum[I^n BesselJ[n, Times[-I z]] Exp[I n th], {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]??

expr = % /.    Power[E, z__ Cos[th__]] :>     Sum[I^n BesselJ[n, Times[z]] Exp[I n th], {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Thanks. Then it needs to be Times[-I z] otherwise it is an incorrect replacement. If I do that, it doesn't help.

The problem is that "RuleDelayed" has the attribute "HoldRest", therefore it does not evaluate the replacement. A dirty trick to force the evaluation anyway is the following. This will invoke the unfortunately undocumented "RuleCondition", that will do the evaluation:
expr /. BesselJ[n, x__] :> Block[{}, Bessel[n, x] /; True]



Better do not work with % in a series of statements. If I set the intermediate result
$$r=\left(\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty } i^n \exp (i\  \text{gmt} \ n) \  J_n\left(\frac{1}{2} (-i) (-1) i m \pi \right)\right) \ \left( \sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty } i^n \exp (i (3 \text{gmt}) n) J_n\left(\frac{1}{18} (-i) (-1) i m \pi \right) \right) $$
without any  Simplify the result is
$$e^{-\frac{1}{2}\ i \  \pi  \ m  \ \cos (\text{gmt})} \ \sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty } i^n e^{3 \ i \ \text{gmt} \ n} J_n\left(-\frac{1}{18} (m \\pi )\right)$$
